# Computing the remainder of two numbers in CRT form

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

Say that we have a set of CRT or RNS moduli $p_1, \dots, p_k$ where $M=\prod_{i=1}^k p_i$ and the CRT representation of two numbers $x,y$, i.e.

- $x_{\mathsf{CRT}} = ([x \bmod p_1], \dots, [x \bmod p_k])$
- $y_{\mathsf{CRT}} = ([y \bmod p_1], \dots, [y \bmod p_k])$.

We'd like to compute the CRT representation of $[x \bmod y]_{\mathsf{CRT}} = ([ (x \bmod y)  \bmod p_1], \dots, [(x \bmod y) \bmod p_k])$ by manipulating only numbers in CRT form.

One idea to solve this is by computing $(x - x/y)$ in their CRT form. The main problem which needs to be tackled is the division $x/y$ in CRT form. There are a couple of methods to solve the integer division in CRT which can be found in a few papers such as [CL06](http://msn.iecs.fcu.edu.tw/~ccc/profile/publish/ij_paper2/IJ-350.pdf#lbib7) or [HK95](https://users.cs.duke.edu/~elk27/bibliography/95/HiKa95.pdf).

In a nutshell those papers compute the reciprocical of $y$ in CRT form and then do a couple of iterations, similar with Newton-Raphson of computing $x/y$ using repeated multiplications. The problem with these methods is that it requires many switches between different CRT representations which are relatively expensive in my model.

I'm thinking that if I restrict $y$ to those that satisfy $\mathsf{gcd}(y, M) = 1$ perhaps the solution might be less expensive but I am unsure how to tackle this. I could also make the primes $p_i$ smooth $\approx 2^n + \epsilon$ but again, usure how this would have better efficiency.

The question I have is whether you are aware of any efficient integer division or modulo reduction which works over CRT representations and has as few CRT conversions as possible.

Comment: It seems to me that the costs for calculating the quotient are the same as calculating the remainder, because if you have one you can easily get the  other by O(k) modular operations. So your question can be reduced to: are there faster algorithms for computing the quotient than these presented in the linked papers?

Comment: Indeed. They solve the problem for general $y$ whereas I could relax a bit the constraints of $y$ by making it co-prime with $M$ but I'm unsure if it helps with anything.